# Route refreshing on redux store change and clicking continuously on Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am using react: 16.6.0 and react-router-dom: 4.3.1 with redux setup

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <App />
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

here is my implementation of routes

```
<Suspense maxDuration={1500} fallback={<BundleLoading />} >
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route exact path='/' component={() => <Dashboard />} />
                                    <Route exact path='/settings' component={() => <Settings />} />
                                    <Route path='**' component={() => <PageNotFound />} />
                                </Switch>
                            </Suspense>
```

when I click on Link component continuously it re-render the component on every click. also whenever my redux store changes(changing theme to light/dark ) than also it re-renders. I have other apps that are implemented the same way but those are working as expected.

i am clueless about this, please help I can update more code if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess that a fat arrow function is the reason. Try to switch like this `<Route path="subroute1" component={SubRoute1} />`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked but  it giving me  a warning "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
"  but I don't care,

Comment: react-router, not Suspense ready yet, use reach router instead

Comment: So does that means I can face more bugs/blocks with react-router until they update it to support suspense, is it a good idea to wait for the update or just move to reach router

Comment: hard to tell for now its all so fresh... can be or not for both

Comment: anyway, thanks for you help, I will probably wait until another major bug comes out. I think I don't have to deal with many routing logic for now, I can switch it easily later